# How to trigger compiled binary execution file in Google Function

Tags: python, go, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

Currently, I'm using Google Function with python which refactors the result of Goolge OCR (Vision API). So, the current structure is as below.

User sends the target image with mobile application -> Trigger the function in Goolge Function -> Sends the result to mobile application.

Since it is quite slow, I am trying to change the process with Golang. So this is my question.

I think although I deploy my golang function to Google Functions, it isn't compiled. The code is compiled when instance is made and runs. However, I want to compile the code and just execute the program when the user triggers. So how can I use compiled file in Google Function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you elaborate please, why do you think so:

> I think although I deploy my golang function to Google Functions, it isn't compiled. The code is compiled when instance is made and runs.

From the best of my understanding, the build happens at the deployment time, as described on the documentation page [Building Cloud Functions Images](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/building):

> When you deploy your function's source code to Cloud Functions, that source is stored in a Cloud Storage bucket. Cloud Build then automatically builds your code into a container image and pushes that image to Container Registry.

There may be a few ways to improve performance and decrease latency (depending on your context, requirements and budget) - see [One-time initialization](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/go-runtime#one-time_initialization) for Go, and [Cloud Functions Execution Environment](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/exec#runtimes) paying attention to the [Cold starts](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/exec#cold_starts) section...

Comment: Thanks. I read all the links you mentioned and it helped a lot. Since the execution time was bit slow than I expected, I  thought the source code was compiled with cold start. So with same environment golang would be faster than python because golang is compiled but python should be interpreted in google cloud instance. Is this assumption reasonable? I'm actually quite confused of container image of python. Container image of golang could be a binary file but what for python? By the way, thanks.

Comment: As a general assumption, I would guess that the Go is to be faster than Python, due to reasons you mentioned. At the same time, quite a lot depends on your requirements and context - what exactly your function is to do, and so on... If your cloud function is to make some network interaction, and some concurrency is possible, and you use Go libraries where the concurrency is used - you might get significant performance benefits, over Python implementation without concurrency. At the same time, in general case, you should be very accurate in case you are to do any async, concurrent processing...

Comment: Here is a blog post about async in cloud functions: https://cloud.google.com/blog/topics/developers-practitioners/avoiding-gcf-anti-patterns-part-5-how-run-background-processes-correctly-python?__s=6lzuvux3jnyafimak2bx